# Hibernate OrphanRemoval is deleting data only from Relationship table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a `RECIPE` table that has OneToMany relationship with the `INGREDIENT` table because a single recipe can have many ingredients. The issue is that if a user deletes an ingredient (which sets all fields (`ingredient_id` and `ingredient`) to NULL by frontend), then the row containing relationship of both the tables `RECIPE_INGREDIENT` is deleted but the row in the `Ingredient` table still exists. Can't we tell Hibernate to delete that rows also?

**Oracle table**

```
create table recipe(id number primary key,
                    name varchar2(25) unique);

create table ingredient(ingredient_id number(4) primary key,
                    ingredient varchar2(40));

create table recipe_ingredient(recipe_id number(4),
                           ingredient_id number(4),
                           constraint recipe_fk foreign key(recipe_id)
                           references recipe(recipe_id),
                           constraint ingredient_fk foreign
                           key(ingredient_id) references
                           ingredient(ingredient_id));
```

**Ingredient and Recipe POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredient", uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="INGREDIENT_ID")
})
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "INGREDIENT_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_ingredient", sequenceName="seq_ingredient")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="seq_ingredient")
    private Integer ingredientId;

    @Column(name = "INGREDIENT")
    private String ingredient;

    /*@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="RECIPE_ID")
    private Recipe recipe;*/

    //getter and setters



@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe")
public class Recipe implements Serializable {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "recipe_ingredient", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id") })
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

//getters and setter
}
```

**DAO Code**

```
public class RecipeDaoImpl implements RecipeDao {
    public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(recipe);
    }
}
```

**Log that shows that the row in `INGREDIENT` table still exists whereas Hibernate is just deleting row from 'RECIPE_INGREDIENT' table.**

Please see following that `ingredient_id` with `null` is deleted. In both cases, it is updating `ingredient.recipe_id` as NULL.

```
Received following from frontend:
RecipeController - Recipe[recipeId=126,name=Sandwich,ingredients=[Ingredient[ingredientId=270,ingredient=Salt],[ingredientId=<null>,quantity=<null>]]]

Hibernate: update RECIPE set NAME=? where RECIPE_ID=?
Hibernate: update ingredient set INGREDIENT=? where INGREDIENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from recipe_ingredient where recipe_id=?
Hibernate: insert into recipe_ingredient (recipe_id, ingredient_id) values (?, ?)
```

So the database table has,

```
INDREDIENT
INGREDIENT_ID   INGREDIENT
271             Salt    
272             Sugar

RECIPE_INDGREDIENT
RECIPE_ID   INDREDIENT_ID
126         271
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the equals() and hashcode() methods *correctly* in the Receipe and Indgredient classes? If not then that could be the cause why the rows in indgredient table are not deleted. Read [this](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) article for more details.

Comment: I have implemented `equal()` and `hashcode()` method in both classes. I have used Eclipse inbuilt feature (Source > Generate equal() and hascode()) to generate these. But still the issue persist and data is not getting deleted from the `INGREDENT` table.

Comment: I used `getSession().merge(recipe)` instead of `getSession().saveOrUpdate(recipe)` and it worked. I was reading other forum/articles and got this idea from there. I am not sure what made difference but code is now working perfectly. Do you have any insight about this?

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your use case - http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/